# javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler error

Tags: jooq

I am getting **"javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler"** error with Java 11 and spring boot 2.1.6. I have these libraries in my classpath

```
classpath group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq', version: '3.10.7'
classpath group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-meta', version: '3.10.7'
classpath group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-codegen', version: '3.10.7'
```

And I have added these gradle dependencies.

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.2'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.2'
compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.2'
compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '2.3.2'
compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
```

May I know, what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade to the latest version of jOOQ. These issues should be resolved starting from jOOQ 3.12. A few related issues:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6477
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6610
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6650
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6879
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7047
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7499